# Token cache serialization in MSAL.NET is not working

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, adal

I am facing some issues when trying to serialize the tokencache, returned from authenticating with MSAL.
I would appreciate any help, since i don't really understand what i am doing wrong.
Here is our situation/problem:

We are currently using ADAL to allow users to authenticate to their SharePoint Online accounts from our desktop application, but want to switch to MSAL.

We have implemented two possible authentication flows. A publicClientApplication, to allow the user authenticating with its currently active Microsoft credentials and a ConfidentialClientApplication, that allows to authenticate with the use of a certificat as you can see in the catch block of the code below:

```
                try
                {
                     Debugger.Launch();
                    if (certificate != null)
                    { 
                        IConfidentialClientApplication m_authContext = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(pClientID)
                            .WithTenantId(m_tenant).WithCertificate(certificate).WithRedirectUri(pClientRedirectURI).Build();
                        var accounts = await m_authContext.GetAccountsAsync();
                        authResult = await m_authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(m_scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IPublicClientApplication m_authContext = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(pClientID).WithTenantId(m_tenant).WithRedirectUri(pClientRedirectURI).Build();
                        var accounts = await m_authContext.GetAccountsAsync();
                        authResult = await m_authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(m_scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {   
                    if (certificate != null)
                    { 
                        IConfidentialClientApplication m_authContext = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(pClientID)
                            .WithTenantId(m_tenant).WithCertificate(certificate).WithRedirectUri(pClientRedirectURI).Build();
                        TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(m_authContext.AppTokenCache);
                        authResult = await m_authContext.AcquireTokenForClient(m_scope).WithForceRefresh(true).ExecuteAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IPublicClientApplication m_authContext = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(pClientID)
                            .WithTenantId(m_tenant).WithRedirectUri(pClientRedirectURI).Build();
                        TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(m_authContext.UserTokenCache);
                        authResult = await m_authContext.AcquireTokenInteractive(m_scope).ExecuteAsync();
                    }
                }
```

So far, the code works fine and the initial authentication is successful in both cases.
The problem now is that we would like to persist the acquired tokens, so that the next time the user starts our program and tries to access SharePoint he does not have to authenticate again. But trying to authenticate silent with the use of a prior stored token does not work, neither for the public nor the confidential application.
The serialization of the AfterAccessNotification however does seem to work, as at least something gets written into the cache file. But reading this data back does not. One thing to point out is that **GetAccountsAsync()** will always return 0.

What i have read so far, from the Microsoft documentation and other questions here, is that of course the inmemory cache of the applications will get lost when recreating it and the solution seems to be the implementation of the TokenCacheHelper. Our helper class is implemented as its suggested in the documentation:

```
    static class TokenCacheHelper
    {
        public static readonly string CacheFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "msalcache.txt";
        private static readonly object FileLock = new object();

        public static void EnableSerialization(ITokenCache tokenCache)
        {
            Debugger.Launch();
            tokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
            tokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
        }

        private static void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(File.Exists(CacheFilePath)
                        ? ProtectedData.Unprotect(File.ReadAllBytes(CacheFilePath),
                                                  null,
                                                  DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                       : null);
        }

        private static void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            Debugger.Launch();
            if (args.HasStateChanged)
            {
                lock (FileLock)
                {
                    // reflect changesgs in the persistent store
                    File.WriteAllBytes(CacheFilePath,
                                        ProtectedData.Protect(args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3(),
                                                                null,
                                                                DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                                        );
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Am i having a major misunderstanding on the use of the TokenCacheHelper or something else here?
Or is there a more simple way on persisting the tokencache?
This seemed to be far less complicated with the use of ADAL.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We found out what was causing the problem. There was simply a call of `TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(m_authContext.UserTokenCache);`
missing before trying to acquire the token silent.

Answer (score 2):

There's no simpler way. I'm using this Mircosoft provided class (TokenCacheHelper) myself and it works very nicely. I'm persisting the token now for several weeks. No problems reading it back and using it.
Generally as far I tested out you must **first** authenticate interactively for many kinds of data you want to read then read the saved token for future actions. You can check in your Azure security center for which data you have authenticate interactively or may authenticate non-interactively.

1. Re-check your security settings for reading accounts in Azure security center.
2. Re-check scopes like: "User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All"
3. Check out the example under https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2 which helped me

Give it try!

PS: I would consider the whole MS-graph library in a "beta state" and still buggy, error prone and not finished. So expect different behavior now and in the future.

Regards